# Sorry, we ran into a problem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

I am using SharePoint Server 2013 and I installed and configured the Office Web Apps server in a separate server and then did the bindings for the SharePoint Server. Now, the files are working fine and I can open them in the browser. However, I am not able to open all the PowerPoint files and some word files from the SharePoint library as shown below:

[image: Word Error].[image: PPT Error]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my issue. The farm status was unhealthy when I executed *Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine* and I removed the OWA farm then create it from scratch and add the http feature using *Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45*. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct. If that's the solution, you should mark it as such.